# How to train a neural net (LSTM) with n grams?

Tags: lstm, text-classification

Currently I'm training with single words only which are converted to a numerical vector. The problem is that all the classification is based on the occurrence of single words, without taking the context into account. Is there a way to feed my neural net with bags of several words?

So, instead of using single words of texts such as (text is already preprocessed):

['seoul' 'u' 'defens' 'secretari' 'jim' 'matti' 'said' 'friday']

I would like to have the LSTM base its classification on the context:

['seoul u defens secretari' 'jim matti said friday']

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: LSTMs are using n-grams internally by nature. This is due to the recurrent connections in the network. So, an LSTM is building something like n-grams, a sentence can be given to the LSTM word by word. Also, it could be possible to feed the LSTM with sentences in order to predict new sentences.